# html-webpack-plugin doesn't generate index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I am trying out html-webpack-plugin for Webpack by following their documentation. But it seems to be not generating the required html file. I have created a small bare-bone project to reproduce the error. [github project to highlight the error](https://github.com/parit/react-webpack-test) I would appreciate if someone can point out my error. Use the following script to see the result in the project directory:

```
npm install 
node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Comment: try to clean `build` folder before `webpack` command

Comment: plugins should not be in modules